# Raspbian ~/.xinitrc File Missing

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, desktop-environment, mate-desktop

I booted up my Raspberry Pi for the first time using the full NOOBS installer... I am using the Raspberry Pi 2 (it has four USBs, one Ethernet, one HDMI, and one micro SD Card port)... I use it over SSH and VNC on my local network...

I was thinking of installing a new Desktop Environment because I found the old one rather boring, and I was used to XFCE with Ubuntu, not Raspberry Pi default Desktop Environment (LXDE) with Raspbian Wheezy =), so I went and was looking at the Raspbian MATE Desktop Environment (a fork off of Gnome) and thought it would be nice, so I proceeded to add `deb http://archive.raspbian.org/mate wheezy main` to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`. I then ran `sudo apt-get update`, and then the two components of MATE with this: `sudo apt-get install mate-core mate-desktop-environment`.

The instructions told me to add `exec mate-session` to my `~/.xinitrc` followed by running the command `startx`. It went completely fine up until I had to edit my `~/.xinitrc`, which happened to be non-existent...

this is the result of running `ls -a`:

```
.
..
.bash_history
.bash_logout
.bashrc
.cache
.config
.dbus
Desktop
.dmrc
.dosbox
Downloads
.fontconfig
.galculator
Games
.gconf
.gnome2
.gstreamer-0.10
.gtk-bookmarks
.gvfs
Hacking
.icons
.idlerc
indiecity
.local
.Mathematica
.minecraft
.noip
.pki
.profile
.pulse
.pulse-cookie
.python_games
Scripts
.sonic-pi
.ssh
.thumbnails
.vnc
weaved-nixinstaller_1.2.13.bin
weaved_software
.WolframEngine
.Xauthority
.xsession-errors
.xsession-errors.old
```

Comment: why you don't use [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/) instead? - that would be the easiest way...

Comment: @DJCrashdummy: is that a distro or a desktop environment?

Comment: [Ubuntu MATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE) is (meanwhile) an official derivative of Ubuntu using [MATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATE_%28software%29) as its desktop environment. -- and they provide an image for the Raspberry Pi 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several ways to achieve your not completely clear goal(s):

1. you can **stay with [Raspbian](http://www.raspbian.org/)**:
   since Raspbian is based on Debian, you can take a look at the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/) for further informations about [`.xinitrc`](https://wiki.debian.org/Xinitrc).
   and if you do so, why you install MATE when you are familiar with and searching for Xfce?
2. if you want to **work with the [MATE Desktop Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATE_%28software%29)** and you are used to Ubuntu (also based on Debian) i highly recommend [Ubuntu MATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE) [for the Raspberry Pi 2](https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/):
   you can easily [install every standalone image](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md) without NOOBS according to the real good [Raspberry Pi Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/).
   *here is an older [tutorial for install and "tweak" MATE](http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMate) on top of Raspbian running on a Raspberry Pi 1.*
3. or if you are looking for a Raspberry Pi **image with Xfce** as default DE you can take a look at [Pidora](http://www.pidora.ca/):
   **BUT** since it is based on [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29), there are some [differences](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Comparison_to_other_distributions#Debian) to all the other Debian based distributions you will notice at least if you are exiting your DE and enter the command line.

Comment: I have used Ubuntu and other Debian-derivatives for a while now, but I decided to try out *pidora*, and it worked... I am currently researching *yum*... It has been a long time since I've used Fedora, so I am also researching the symlinks...